# What does this JavaScript Regular Expression /[^\d.-] mean?

Tags: javascript, regex

We had a developer here who had added following line of code to a web application:

```
var amount = newValue.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
```

The particular line deals with amount values that a user may enter into a field.

I know the following about the regular expression:

1. that it replaces the matches with empty strings (i.e. removes them)
2. that **/g** is a flag that means to match all occurrences inside "newValue"
3. that the brackets **[]** denote a special group
4. that **^** means beginning of the line
5. that **d** means digits

Unfortunately I do not know enough to determine what kind of strings this should match. I checked with some web-based regex testers if it matches e.g. strings like **98.-** and other alternatives with numbers but so far no luck.

My problem is that it seems to make IE very slow so I need to replace it with something else.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
Thanks to all who replied. I tried not just Google but sites like myregextester.com, regular-expressions.info, phpliveregex.com, and others. My problem was misunderstanding the meaning of **^** and expecting that this required a numeric string like 44.99.

Comment: Just try it... I don't see why you need to ask anyone. Pump some strings into the `.replace` and see what you get. *Spoiler Alert* it returns only digits, periods, and hyphens... You can even open a JS console in your browser and test by running something like: `'abcABC123$%^.--_'.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');`

Comment: @SLaks: 2 is correct. No?

Comment: Might be helpful for future reference. Take a look at the description from here http://regex101.com/r/rV6mY0

Comment: @BlueSkies: He changed the numbering (Or I made a typo).  I meant what is now 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ^ character is a negation character.

```
var newValue = " x44x.-x ";
var amount = newValue.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
console.log(amount);
```

will print

```
44.-
```

I suspect the developer maybe just wanted to remove trailing whitespaces? I would rather try to parse the string for numbers and remove anything else.

Answer (score 13):

Inside the group, when the `^` is the first character, it works as a negation of the character matches. In other words, it's saying match any character that are not the ones in the group.

So this  will mean "match anything that is not a digit, a period, or a hyphen".

Comment: @putvande: What do you mean?

Comment: @putvande: Oh, OK. Yeah I assumed OP knew what the other characters meant, but you're right, good idea to include the description.

Comment: Yeah, it is always good to give a full explanation. The more likely people will upvote / accept your answer.